# How to Remove the Timestamp in a File?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following data:

```
DOBirth
2/17/1937 00:00:00:00
3/2/1941 00:00:00
8/9/1928 00:00
1/1/1971 0:00
9/3/1963 :00
```

What is the appropriate way that I can use to remove the extraneous zeros after the birth column?

The output should be like:

```
DOBirth
2/17/1937
3/2/1941 
8/9/1928 
1/1/1971 
9/3/1963
```

Comment: No expression, split and take the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by space and return the first item:

```
>>> s = """DOBirth
... 2/17/1937 00:00:00:00
... 3/2/1941 00:00:00
... 8/9/1928 00:00
... 1/1/1971 0:00
... 9/3/1963 :00"""
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     print(line.split(" ", 1)[0])
... 
DOBirth
2/17/1937
3/2/1941
8/9/1928
1/1/1971
9/3/1963
```

where `1` in `line.split(" ", 1)` is the `maxsplit` value - splitting by the first space only, since it is not relevant for us what comes after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import re

text = '2/17/1937 00:00:00:00'

m = re.search('(.*)\s[0\:]*$', text)
if m:
    found = m.group(1);
    print found
```

So in found variable you will get respective date that you want. I am here looking for all the character before space followed by 0 or colon till end.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use regex with code sample. I hope this helps.